# Google Sheets Script: If Cell contents are not found on destination sheet, copy it from source sheet into new row at top of destination sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm working on a personal finance worksheet. I have an add-on that pulls in transactions into my Import sheet. I would like a script to copy it over into my Transactions sheet if it's not already there, based on the transaction ID. It could just take the whole row.

Here's my test sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KINS7xMydnycHG9xXBhA5w04FaXPM_6YjWUC3weu2OU/edit?usp=sharing

I found the following script, but it's not doing anything. How would I need to modify it to accomplish my goal? Or would something else entirely be better?

```
function copyRowtoSheet2() { 
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KINS7xMydnycHG9xXBhA5w04FaXPM_6YjWUC3weu2OU").getSheetByName('Import');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KINS7xMydnycHG9xXBhA5w04FaXPM_6YjWUC3weu2OU").getSheetByName('Transactions'); 
  var values1 = s1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getDataRange().getValues();
  var resultArray = [];
  for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++){
    var keep = false;
    for(var p=0; p < values2.length ; p++){
      Logger.log(values1[n][0]+' =? '+values2[p][0]);
      if( values1[n][0] == values2[p][0] && values1[n][1] !== values2[p][1]){
        resultArray.push(values1[n]);
        Logger.log('true');
        break ;// remove this if values are not unique and you want to keep all occurrences...
      }
    }
  }  
  s2.getRange(+1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

Comment: Is your transactions page what you want it to look like when completed? You're updating the values in Columns g and over?

Comment: You probably don't need a google script to accomplish this. A more practical approach would be use the Query Function of just a filter.  I threw an example in your file.

Comment: What do you mean by "If it's not there"?

Comment: The add-on overwrites the data on the import sheet when it updates, so I just want to send the new transactions over to the Transactions sheet. 

@Cooper, I mean if that transaction ID is not already found on the Transactions sheet.

Comment: And yes you are correct pgSystemTester, I’m updating the Transactions sheet in G and over.

Comment: If the transaction Ids are unique for each row then why do you have to check two columns?

Comment: I just need to see if the transaction id is present on the transactions sheet and if not, copy it over there, ideally into a new row at the top. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  var s1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KINS7xMydnycHG9xXBhA5w04FaXPM_6YjWUC3weu2OU").getSheetByName('Import');
  var s2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1KINS7xMydnycHG9xXBhA5w04FaXPM_6YjWUC3weu2OU").getSheetByName('Transactions'); 
  var values1 = s1.getRange(2,1,s1.getLastRow()-1,6).getValues();
  var values2 = s2.getRange(2,1,s2.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

  var resultArray = [];
  var discard 

// looks at each id from Import and checks it against the ids in Transactions. If it doesn't exist it pushes it into a new array called resultarray
  for(var n=0; n < values1.length ; n++){
    discard = 0
    for(var p=0; p < values2.length ; p++){
          if( values1[n][0] == values2[p][0]){
      discard = 1
        }
      }
     Logger.log(values1[n][0] + "   discard = " + discard)
     if (discard == 0) {resultArray.push(values1[n]) }
  
  }  


// find the first emoty row in the ID column in Transations
var column = s2.getRange('A:A');
  var values = column.getValues(); // get all data in one call
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }


// Stops the script if there isn't any resuls to paste in
if (resultArray == "") {
  Logger.log("No New results")
  return;}


// Pastes the resultarray in at the bottom
s2.getRange(ct+1,1,resultArray.length,resultArray[0].length).setValues(resultArray);
}
```

Your original script was checking 2 columns where I think you only wanted 1 column checking.

The revised script uses a nested "for" loop to take each ID from Import and check it against all the values in Transactions. If it exists it changes the "Discard" variable to 1.

After it's checked the entire Transaction columns it checks the discard variable. If it's still 0 (indicating the ID doesn't exist in Transactions) then it pushes the row of data to results array.
It then gets the results array, finds the next available row to add it to and pastes it into Transactions

Comment: That is exactly what I'm hoping for! Thanks for your reply. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but if I take a Transaction ID out of the Transaction sheet, I'm expecting the script to then add a new row with the missing ID. But it's no doing anything.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Sorry, I added something at the last minute to prevent errors if there were no new rows but I didn't test it. I've edited my original answer with the correct code.

Comment: That works great! Thank you! I would love it if it could insert the new row at the top, instead of the bottom. How big a deal would that be?

Comment: No worries, glad that's working for you. If you get chance could you accept my answer by clicking the tick below the up and down arrows? It would help others in the future and also gives me more points to help other people myself.

Comment: Regarding the new row at the top, it is certainly possible, although if you expect the data to keep growing then it'd slow the script down eventually if you were inserting rows. Might be better to add the lines at the bottom and then sort by date (assuming you are happy with them in date order, (rather than date and time of day order)